# Dynamically adding tomcat to a cluster - ehcache xml configurations files must be manually adjusted?

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, ehcache

I have a spring web application that is running on a tomcat cluster (currently 2 tomcats and a load balancer) with session replication and all the good stuff ..

My intention is to be able to startup additional tomcats servers in a fairly easy way (just startup)

My problem currently is the spring xml files that are part of my web application.

for example - my ehcache.xml:

```
<!-- Cluster Configuration -->

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=32" />

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="**hostName=localhost**, **port=40004**, socketTimeoutMillis=2000" />
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="50000" eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true"
    diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

As you can see the **port** field and **hostname** in that xml should be unique on each tomcat server.
I dont want to manually change this field before i'm starting up a new tomcat server.

Are there any solutions out there for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 main options.

1) You can set a system property when you run tomcat and pass those as variables. For example you can pass the parameter `-DehcachePort=xxx` and then in the xml set that value as ${ehcachePort}. I cannot find a link to the documentation of this feature, but it's mentioned [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/faq#how-do-i-make-the-terracotta-url-available-in-different-environments-using-different-terracotta-servers)

1.1) If you cannot set the system properties from the command line, you can write a tiny class that calls System.setProperty **before** you load the ehchache.xml.

2) Instantiate the Ehcache objects from code. It's basically the same as above, but you have to read a properties file and instantiate anything that you require. Ehcache supports fluent builders, which are quite easy to read (compared to the verbosity of XML).

Answer (score 0):

EhCachce integrates flawlessly with Terracoyta.

If for some reason you don't want to use Teracotta, you can use Spring's PropertyPlaceholder functionality to replace them based on environment variables or properties.